# WSL2 connect to host without disabling the windows firewall

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-firewall

I simply want to connect from my WSL2 Ubuntu installation to my host windows on port 8529.

What I tried:

- Disabled my public firewall. This works but is no option.
- I added bash, [wsl](https://devdojo.com/mvnarendrareddy/access-windows-localhost-from-wsl2), and the ubuntu app to the firewall rules. This didn't work
- I added a [firewall rule for the virtual network adapter of wsl](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1032#issuecomment-792892600). Didn't work either

This question has been ask quite a view times, but none of the usual answers worked for me.

Comment: If disabling the public firewall on the host helped, why don't you add a firewall rule on the host to allow this one connection? And why the public and not the private firewall?

Comment: I tried to add a rule, but it just didn't work (the last 2 points on my list). I tried to disable the private firewall an nothing happened only when I disabled the public firewall.

Comment: I had the same issue, port- or even interface-based rules such as `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL_Inbound" -Direction Inbound
  -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)"  -Action Allow` just don't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable the firewall only for the *vEthernet (WSL)* interface. This way you will allow connections from WSL while still having the firewall protect your computer from external threats.

- Go to Firewall Settings and click on *Advanced Settings*
- Click *Windows Defender Firewall Properties*
- Select *Public Profile* tab
- Click Customize *Protected network connections*
  [image]
- Unclick *vEthernet (WSL)*

Comment: It works but I wonder why the firewall rule 'New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)" -Action Allow' does not work

Comment: This works and is still better than totally disabling the firewall but in company environments with managed workstations (for example Microsoft Intune) this might give administrators red lights flashing because of noncompliant firewall settings. No problem if your admin doesn't care or can be bribed but I also didn't get any working rules set up for the WSL adapter.

Comment: This can be scripted (PowerShell): `Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Public -DisabledInterfaceAliases "vEthernet (WSL)"` (disables for _Public_ profile only)

Comment: @sudoqux I don't have access to change it in the UI, but I could run the PS command. However, after running it for all three of public, private, domain, I still cannot reach :8026 on WSL.

Comment: @mbomb007 Try verifying that it was disabled, by running `Get-NetFirewallProfile | Select Name,DisabledInterfaceAliases`. If _vEthernet (WSL)_ is listed under _DisabledInterfaceAliases_, i don't think it is a firewall issue.

Comment: @sudoqux Yeah, it turned out it wasn't a firewall issue, as I could manually change the binding port and it'd work. I just had to restart the computer, and it was fixed. I think Windows somehow had occupied the port during installation of updates, because the port was bound.

Comment: For some reason I need to run Powershell script every time I run Intellij that uses WSL 2. Hope this manual approach will fix it permanently

Comment: For me also those settings were disabled in Group Policy but the issue was that trying to connect a wrong IP address and the correct one was 172.24.240.1. You need to run `ip route show | grep -i default | awk '{ print $3}'` **in WSL** to determine the correct address as described [in MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking). So in the end it started working without any changes in the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my case I use CentOS 7 WSL App. I didn't have success manage on Norton 360. So in `In Rules` (I don't how is on English SO) I've added do CentOS 7 app. And worked for me.

CentOS 7:
[image: CentOS 7]

And I have success to ping to google.com