# WSL2 ubuntu can access host IP but is unable to access host port

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Windows configs:

1. Running a sample web server with port 5000 opened (see picture 1)
2. Windows firewall fully closed

WSL2:

1. Can successfully access the Internet and ping windows with host IP or `$(hostname).local`, but unable to `curl http://172.18.16.1:5000`

```
sandowner@ENIGMATIC-MACHINE:~$ hostip=$(ip route | grep default | awk '{print $3}')
sandowner@ENIGMATIC-MACHINE:~$ echo $hostip
172.18.16.1
sandowner@ENIGMATIC-MACHINE:~$ ping 172.18.16.1
PING 172.18.16.1 (172.18.16.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.18.16.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.514 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.16.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.690 ms
^C
sandowner@ENIGMATIC-MACHINE:~$ ping $(hostname).local
PING ENIGMATIC-MACHINE (172.18.16.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ENIGMATIC-MACHINE (172.18.16.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.355 ms
64 bytes from ENIGMATIC-MACHINE (172.18.16.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.729 ms
^C
sandowner@ENIGMATIC-MACHINE:~$ curl http://172.18.16.1:5000
^C (will timeout)
```

2. Host's 5000 port also cannot be accessed from a WSL2 browser and it will end with `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` (see picture 2)

[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is the port 5000 service even available on non-localhost? Is the firewall set to allow remote connections to this port/application?

Comment: Hi @DanielB, thanks for the insight that I run the service only on localhost, and changed the host address to "0.0.0.0" resolved my issue, port 5000 now available on all virtual IPs

Comment: Please add an answer with the solution and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I started to answer this as well, but realized that @DanielB and I had both already answered the same question in [Cannot communicate with Windows localhost from WSL2](https://superuser.com/questions/1732399/cannot-communicate-with-windows-localhost-from-wsl2).  Recommend closing this one.  Nonemaw - Note that I did mention the "bind" problem in my [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69407064/11810933) that you commented on ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to connect *from WSL 2 to the host*, there are no special mechanisms in place. WSL 2 runs in a VM and is a remote host as far as the Windows networking stack is concerned. That means:

- You cannot reach applications bound to `localhost`, any IP on `127.0.0.0/8` or `::1`
- The firewall must allow the inbound connection

The WSL 2 virtual network unfortunately has totally unpredictable dynamic addresses, so listening only there means you’ll have to update the network service configuration all the time. It is easier to bind to `0.0.0.0` or `::` (“all interfaces”) instead. This means everyone will be able to connect, so make sure you’re aware of the consequences if you’re on an untrusted network.

Comment: Hello. I'm facing the same issue. Can ping localhost from WSL and access localhost:8080 from Windows, but can't access my application from WSL. I've started it on Windows with `quarkusDev -Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0` but it's still unreachable from WSL. Inbound Windows Firewall Rule is set for 8080 and I've tried diverse addresses with curl like 'localhost','127.0.0.1', and result of `grep -m 1 nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'`. I've modified both hosts files (Windows + WSL) and added `127.0.0.1 example.test
::1 example.test localhost` as well. Am I missing something still?

Comment: Got it working now, not sure what it was, but `grep -m 1 nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'` this address needs to be used. Thank you