# SSDP Discovery not working for IP address other than WSL's instance IP

Tags: linux, networking, ip, windows-subsystem-for-linux, udp

I am trying to port a process from Windows to WSL/Linux. Earlier, two Windows process were communicating through TCP connection after successful SSDP discovery. Now, I want similar communication to work from Windows to Linux (WSL). I had been using localhost/127.0.0.1 in the Windows<->Windows case, but SSDP discovery seems to work only on WSL's instance IP for Windows<->WSL .

**ifconfig** in WSL gives:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.26.253.18  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.26.255.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fed7:82b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:d7:08:2b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 422  bytes 72257 (72.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 299  bytes 27676 (27.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 378  bytes 19949 (19.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 378  bytes 19949 (19.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

SSDP discovery works for 172.26.253.18 when I am running a process in Windows and other in WSL.

Possible reason I can think of is when we use 127.0.0.1 within WSL, it refers to the loopback interface of the WSL environment itself. SSDP packets sent to 127.0.0.1 stay within the WSL environment and aren't visible to the host Windows environment or other devices on your local network.

Comment: Sounds like a programming question which should be asked on SO with the appropriate code blocks

Comment: @Ramhound It's not a programming question and was already closed as off-topic on Stack Overflow. As it was a networking question regarding SSDP not working between Windows and WSL, I asked the OP to repost here. Since SSDP requires a multicast address, AFAIK it's simply not going to work between WSL2 and Windows.

Comment: @Piyush If you have Windows 11 23H2, try turning on Mirrored networking mode as I show in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1732513/1210833). I have no idea if SSDP will work with that, but I think it might.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - It was closed because the author didn’t provide any code, and how would I know, the author submitted this question to SO since it wasn’t migrated?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't believe that I implied that you should know. Apologies if I gave you that impression.  I'm just pointing out that it is not a programming question and that it belongs *here*, not on SO.  *If* you can see (and I don't know if you can) the Close-Reason on the SO version of the question, it's *"Not about programming ...."*  If it was due to lack of a code, then it would have been closed as either *"Needs debugging details"* or *"Needs details or clarity"*.  Just because a networking issue is found while doing development doesn't make it a programming question ;-).