# How to access http server on host from WSL2?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have a python http.server running on the windows host:

```
C:\> python3 -m http.server 8000
```

The host has two ip addresses:

```
C:\> ipconfig

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):
  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.28.224.1                                                                        
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0   

Wireless LAN adapter WLAN:
  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 123.123.123.123
```

The http server can be accessed from the host itself through both ip, together with localhost:

```
C:\> curl 123.123.123.123:8000

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!DOCTYPE HTML>
                    <html lang="en">
...

C:\> curl 172.28.224.1:8000

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!DOCTYPE HTML>
                    <html lang="en">
...

C:\> curl 127.0.0.1:8000

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!DOCTYPE HTML>
                    <html lang="en">
...
```

But I can't access the http server from inside WSL2, even though the host can be ping-ed:

```
~$ curl 172.28.224.1:8000
(hanging)

~$  ping 172.28.224.1
PING 172.28.224.1 (172.28.224.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.28.224.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.967 ms
64 bytes from 172.28.224.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=1.77 ms
...
```

I have already set up some firewall rules:

```
C:\> New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName WSL -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)" -Direction Inbound -Action Allow -Protocol TCP
C:\> New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName WSL -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)" -Direction Outbound -Action Allow -Protocol TCP
C:\> New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName wsl -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 8000 -Action Allow -Protocol TCP
C:\> New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName wsl -Direction Outbound -LocalPort 8000 -Action Allow -Protocol TCP
```

Forwarding from WSL2 to 127.0.0.1 on host doesn't work either:

```
C:\> netsh int por add v4tov4 8000 127.0.0.1 8000 172.28.224.1
```

```
~$ curl 172.28.224.1:8000
(hanging)
```

Does anyone know if I'm missing anything for accessing the host from WSL2? If I'm not, how should I debug this?

Comment: It looks like a firewall issue. See https://superuser.com/questions/1714002/wsl2-connect-to-host-without-disabling-the-windows-firewall.

Comment: Sorry, meant to write up an answer on this yesterday, but yes, my guess right now is a firewall issue.  It's likely that there's a "Deny" rule that got put in place the first time you tried to access it.  If that's the case, you'll probably need to find and remove that Deny rule in order for the Allow rules that you created to take effect.